# Styled components - Correct way of approach

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using styled components in my project.

Consider the following piece of code

```
import { Footer, FooterLeft, FooterRight, NavLink } from './footer_styles';

const FooterView = ({ prop }) => (
  <Footer className="row">
    <FooterLeft>
      &copy;Sample company, LLC
    </FooterLeft>

    <FooterRight>
      <NavLink to="#" className="footer-link">Privacy Policy</NavLink>
      <span className="separator"> | </span>
      <NavLink to="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</NavLink>
    </FooterRight>
  </Footer>
);
```

So i have the following questions.

1) Can i use bootstrap classes in styled components like what is shown in the code? Is this the correct approach? If not, how to use bootstrap styles along with styled components?

2) Do i need to create a component for each element in dom? For example, in the code that is shown, there is a span tag with class name "separator" for which the styles are added as follows

```
export const FooterRight = styled.div`
  .separator {
    float: left;
  }
  .footer-link {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }

`;
```

Is this approach correct? or

Do i need to create a separate component for separator?

I am a bit confused here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap class for style your component, it is nothing wrong. But it better if you use the React Bootstrap, library optimize for React. For example, the drop-down button you can use bootstrap class because it will use Jquery to execute the animation. But you shouldn't do it because Jquery manipulates the real DOM, React manipulate the virtual DOM so it is not good for performance.

You can read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

The answer still yes, with the class to style the component, should use it to reduce the time for coding, with anything related to Jquery, just use the React Component.
I suggest you use the reactstrap, pretty similar to Bootstrap: https://reactstrap.github.io

Another thing, there is many ways to style component, but I am using CSS module, just need to create a CSS file with add-on module of the file name like this:

```
styleComponent.css --> styleComponent.module.css
```

And then import to your project:

```
import styles from './styleComponent.module.css'
```

And then you can style your component with normal css:

```
<div className={styles.separator} >  Hello World </div>
```

In styleComponent.module.css:

```
.separator{
height: 20px;
background: black;
}
.separator:hover{
background: white;
}
```

It is more easy to manage your project because every single component it has a CSS file to go with it and the className is unique mean locally, Webpack will automatically convert the className 'separator' to '2djfas_separator' that will solve your problem with naming class in CSS.

Hope it helps a little bit for your project!!!